# Unable to Telnet on AWS-EC2 instance in private Subnet VPC VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, amazon-vpc

I have a VPN tunnel setup between Local Infrastructure and EC2 instances. 
I am able to ssh on Ec2 Instance. Also I can do SSH from EC2 to some other Local System.

I have installed a service which connects on port 8440 and 8441 and few other port. The issue I am facing is, I am not able to telnet from Ec2 system to local system on some port. and It is random, sometime port 8440 works some time port 8441 works. Obviously I have verified that these port is in Listning state and I am able to connect from other non EC2 system. at few occasion even ssh give timeout, as work around, after rebooting ec2 system, ssh start working. is the AWS VPN tunnel is this much unreliable?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest enabling VPC Flow Logs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html), which will allow you to understand where the traffic is blocked. See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A5L4jT-K9I for a video that talks about VPC Flow Logs...

Comment: Can you share your SG rules so others can confirm they're 'proper'?

Comment: VPC flow logs is good idea for such network related scenario. but in this case it is not much helpful.